# How to parse constructor arguments on contract creation transaction using ethers.js?

Tags: ethers.js, abi, constructor, decoding

Ethers.js has a `parseTransaction` function that can be used in the following way to extract arguments from any transaction on a deployed contract.

```js
const txDescription = contractInfo.interface.parseTransaction({
  data: tx.input,
  value: tx.value,
});
```

However, this doesn't work for constructor calls. How should one go about extracting constructor arguments from a deploy transaction using ethers.js?